# create a new column that contains a list of values from subsequent rows of partition by ID

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like below,

[image]

and want to create a new column that contains a list of values from another column subsequent rows like below,

[image]

for copy paste: timestamp ID Value

```
date_time   ID  s_val
2021-12-03 04:03:45  ID1     O
2021-12-03 04:03:46  ID1     P
2021-12-03 04:03:47  ID1     Q
2021-12-03 04:03:48  ID1     R
2021-12-03 04:03:49  ID1     NULL
2021-12-03 04:03:50  ID1     S
2021-12-03 04:03:51  ID1     T
2021-12-04 11:09:03  ID2     A
2021-12-04 11:09:04  ID2     B
2021-12-04 11:09:05  ID2     C
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Snowflake does not support cumulative window frames for LISTAGG, I wrote this one:

```
SELECT m.date_time, m.ID, m.s_val, 
      ( SELECT LISTAGG( s.s_val) FROM mydata s WHERE s.ID= m.ID and s.date_time <= m.date_time   ) new_val
FROM mydata m
order by m.ID, m.date_Time;



+---------------------+-----+-------+---------+
|      DATE_TIME      | ID  | S_VAL | NEW_VAL |
+---------------------+-----+-------+---------+
| 2021-12-03 40:03:45 | ID1 | O     | O       |
| 2021-12-03 40:03:46 | ID1 | P     | OP      |
| 2021-12-03 40:03:47 | ID1 | Q     | OPQ     |
| 2021-12-03 40:03:48 | ID1 | R     | OPQR    |
| 2021-12-03 40:03:49 | ID1 | NULL  | OPQR    |
| 2021-12-03 40:03:50 | ID1 | S     | OPQRS   |
| 2021-12-03 40:03:51 | ID1 | T     | OPQRST  |
| 2021-12-04 11:09:03 | ID2 | A     | A       |
| 2021-12-04 11:09:04 | ID2 | B     | AB      |
| 2021-12-04 11:09:05 | ID2 | C     | ABC     |
+---------------------+-----+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Was just editing with this query +1.

Comment: Thanks Atil, your answer gave me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: can we have something like s.date_time - m.date_time > X  in the where clause,   instead of s.date_time <= m.date_time?

Comment: @John yes, it should work.